# Count how many payments are by cashondelivery, paypal, payu etc...?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to count total number of cashondelivery, paypal, payu, ccavenue from order table.

In order table there is column of payment_method.
In that column there are multiple options for payment.

I want to count how many payment by cashondelivery, paypal, payu etc.... (while using yii framwork).

```
        $list = Order::model()->findAll(payment_method=cashondelivery);
        var_dump($list);
            exit;
```

How I can do this so that my output is as follows

```
cashondelivery = 50
paypal =         25
payu =           35
```

Comment: Can you share the query you wrote in model for this, or you are asking what code should be written in model?

Comment: I am asking what code should be written in controller for my questation?

Comment: In that case you should share the output you are getting from `var_dump($list);`

Comment: CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cashondelivery' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `_order` `t` WHERE payment_method=cashondelivery (D:\PHPServer\Amogam\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:543)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$CodCount = Order::model()->countByAttributes(array(
                'payment_method'=>'cashondelivery'
));
echo $CodCount; //returns number of cashondelivery
....//similarly for other payment types
```

or,

```
$CodCount = Order::model()->count("payment_method=:val", array("val" => "cashondelivery"));
echo $CodCount; //returns number of cashondelivery
....//similarly for other payment types
```

or,

```
$dbCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
               SELECT payment_method,COUNT(*) as tot FROM `order` GROUP BY `payment_method`
            ");
$data = $dbCommand->queryAll();

foreach($data AS $val) {
        echo "Payment Method: ".$val["payment_method"]." total: ".$val["tot"]."<br/>";
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Payment Mode: cashondelivery total: 50
Payment Mode: paypal total: 25
Payment Mode: payu total: 35
```